# CSS file not working unless I move the whole folder/project to Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I have a basic webpage/JavaScript example and the CSS doesn't apply to the project unless I move the entire project from (approx 5 subfolders in my Downloads Folder) to the Desktop (No sub folders).

The CSS magically works when I move it to a new location and I didn't change a single line of code in the 2 versions, they are identical. What could be causing this?

Note: Someone did suggest it may have had something to do with VSCode and how I opened the non-working version there first instead of using another editor but that seems far fetched to me.

Original Location
[image]

Now on Desktop
[image]

Version where CSS doesn't work - File structure
[image]

Here is where I declare the script tag
[image: Here is where I declare the script tag]

This version that I copied and put on the desktop works fine somehow
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure from your VS Code? Also, your styles source path from your html?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it up in a minute ~

Comment: Is this what you wanted @KvnG.

Comment: Is the name of the project file is Basics-0-STARTING-PROJECT
if am right put the app.css file in the assets folder and change the < Link href=assets/app.css >  try it ( am waiting)

Comment: Omg I think that worked...and I have no idea why @KirollosMallak
Could you explain why this worked but moving the project to my desktop also worked??

Comment: the assets file is the main folder of your project (sometimes we called the main folder is site root), So all files of the project must be in the main folder so if you want to link any file from the main folder or site root just write it directly  you don't need to write site root name, just write file name you want 
like this href="styles/app.css"  needn't write assets and that is the best way 

I want to ask you a question to make sure understand.
why The assets folder is the main folder or site root of the project?

Comment: Ohh I see. Well I thought that basics-01-starting-project was my site root because it's the parent folder for index.html. But ok, since all my main folders are in assets I guess it's assets. And I get that I don't have to write the site root name, but then why does this exact code work when I move basic-01-SP to my desktop without changing the code?

Comment: it's good to understand how site root working >> but why when you move the Basic file to the desktop  actually don't know